# Не работает docker

Tags: docker

сейчас я пытаюсь начать работу с docker, но есть некоторые проблемы. Установил его, но он не запускается (выводится ошибка *Docker Desktop is shutting down.*)[image: Такая ошибка выводится при запуске Docker desctop]

При попытке использования docker В VS code Так же выводится ошибка
*(error during connect: This error may indicate that t
he docker daemon is not running.: Post "http://%2F%2
F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/images/create?fromIm
age=container&tag=latest": open //./pipe/docker_engi
ne: The system cannot find the file specified. )*

Пересмотрел множество гайдов, но ничего не помогает. Если кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой или знает решения, буду благодарен, если вы сможете помочь.

Виртуализацию включил (процессор AMD)
Скачивал через официальный сайт docker (https://www.docker.com/get-started)

Comment: Кроме аппаратной виртуализации, должна быть 64 битная винда не ниже Pro

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit, по системный требованиям для докера вроде подходит

Comment: в процессах докер крутится? Антивирусы не блокируют?

Comment: Да, есть docker Desctop и Docker.Service в диспетчере задач